# Escaping special characters in VCAP_SERVICES

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am having some problems when I try to put some "special" character as value of my environment variable like `! ' %` etc.

Is there a way to escape them?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I have shared it with the Bluemix Development Team and they are actively looking into whether they can make this scenario consistent between the CLI and the dashboard. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I found it is not possible to use special characters in `VCAP_SERVICES` and `VCAP_APPLICATION`, probably because of security concerns.

The workaround would be to create a [`user-provided service`](http://blog.4loeser.net/2015/10/utilizing-user-provided-services-to.html), define the variable there, bind the service to the app and retrieve the information via the service.

Answer (score 1):

For ordinary user-added environment variables (ie not VCAP_*), the command line will let you do it as long as you escape them from the shell in the usual ways. E.g. here I used single quotes:

```
$ cf set-env mjfmsb DUDE '!@#$%^&*()'
Setting env variable 'DUDE' to '!@#$%^&*()' for app mjfmsb in org mfraioli / space dev as mfraioli...
OK
TIP: Use 'cf restage mjfmsb' to ensure your env variable changes take effect
$ cf env mjfmsb | grep DUDE
DUDE: !@#$%^&*()
```

Not sure why the dashboard doesn't allow the same.